# grep results: how to format output file with one result for each line

Tags: bash, file, grep, output

I am parsing a text file with a grep command in bash. I would like to print the output in another txt file. I am using this line:

`grep 'ACCESSION' chrom_CDS_2.txt | awk '{print $0'\n'}' > accession_out.txt`

The result in the accession_out.txt is like this:

[image]

Instead if I open accession_out.txt in Microsoft Word I have the result that I have tried to format with my bash command:

```
ACCESSION   AC087816
ACCESSION   AC091485
ACCESSION   AC092153
ACCESSION   AC092156
ACCESSION   AC092159
ACCESSION   AC092165
ACCESSION   AC092176
ACCESSION   AC092178
ACCESSION   AC092206
ACCESSION   AC092431
ACCESSION   AC092455
ACCESSION   AC092461
ACCESSION   AC092533 AC027148
ACCESSION   AC092567 AC040931
ACCESSION   AC092569 AC068689
ACCESSION   AC092570 AC060792
ACCESSION   AC092573 AC015764
ACCESSION   AC092575 AC018378
ACCESSION   AC092587 AC023965
ACCESSION   AC092598 AC027781
ACCESSION   AC092603 AC073396
```

Could someone please explain to me how can I obtain the same visualization of Word editor in Notepad?

Seems that Notepad disregard the '\n' tag.

Thank you.

Comment: Because you need `\r\n` to see line breaks in Notepad.

Comment: Use `unix2dos` on the output to insert the "missing" `\r`.

Comment: Yes, unix2dos works solved the problem thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` for fixing the problem is an idea, after some adjustments.
You need `\r` (the Windows linefeed) and use double quotes.

```
grep 'ACCESSION' chrom_CDS_2.txt | awk '{print $0 "\r"}' > accession_out.txt
```

When you use `awk`, you do not need `grep`:

```
awk '/ACCESSION/ {print $0 "\r"}' chrom_CDS_2.txt > accession_out.txt
```

Another possibility is using `sed`: By default don't print lines. When `ACCESSION` is part of the line, replace the complete line with the complete line (`&`, matched part), followed by `\r` and use `/p` for printing it.

```
sed -n 's/.*ACCESSION.*/&\r/p' chrom_CDS_2.txt > accession_out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed s'@ACCESSION@%ACCESSION@'g accession_out.txt | tr '%' '\n' > acc2.txt
mv acc2.txt accession_out.txt
```

Adding carriage returns is very tricky.  AFAIK, tr and ed are the only two utilities which can do it.  It used to be possible to use octals for such things, but that is deep magic which virtually no one probably knows any more.

Comment: The Microsoft Word output shows that the file has `\n` characters and is missing `\r`. You are adding an additional `\n`. No deep magic is needed for adding '\r', simple things like `unix2dos` can be used.